# Why would formview disappear in Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, formview

I know I must be missing something simple but I cannot find it so I will pose the question here. I have a formview with two templates (item and edititem).

The form is bound to the itemtemplate in the `page_Load` event and works fine.  However, if is use `!IsPostBack` in the code-behind, the formview disappears when the edit button is clicked. If I remove the postback check from `page_load`, then the form view appears after the edit button is clicked.

The page does have viewstate enabled.

In general, what steps are needed to get the formview to transition between modes correctly?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        source = Session["Source"].ToString();
        acctType = Session["AccountType"].ToString();
        acctNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["AccountNumber"]);

        if (source == "LifeLineDS")
        {
            ObjectDataSource fvObjDS = new ObjectDataSource();
            fvObjDS.TypeName = "LifelineDataAccess.LifelineSubscriber";
            fvObjDS.SelectMethod = "GetLifelineDSSubscriber";

            fvObjDS.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("AcctType", TypeCode.String, acctType));
            fvObjDS.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("AcctNumber", TypeCode.String, Session["AccountNumber"].ToString()));
            fvObjDS.DataBind();

            if (fvObjDS != null)
            {
                fvSubscriber.DataSource = fvObjDS;  //subscriber.ToString();
                fvSubscriber.DataBind();

                initialProgramValue = (fvSubscriber.FindControl("txtEligibility") as TextBox).Text;
            }                
        }
// more code for other sources...
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fvSubscriber.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    fvSubscriber.DataSource = Session["subscriber"];  //Adding this line resolved !IsPostBack problem
    fvSubscriber.DataBind();

    ObjectDataSource programsObjDS = new ObjectDataSource();
    programsObjDS.TypeName = "LifelineDataAccess.LifelineSubscriber";
    programsObjDS.SelectMethod = "GetPrograms";

    DropDownList ddlEligibility = ((DropDownList)(fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")));

    if (ddlEligibility != null)
    {
        ddlEligibility.DataSource = programsObjDS;
        ddlEligibility.DataTextField = "ProgramName";
        ddlEligibility.DataValueField = "ProgramName";

        ddlEligibility.SelectedValue = initialProgramValue; // Set selected value to subscribers current program
        ddlEligibility.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
fvSubscriber.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
fvSubscriber.DataBind();
```

seems to not to set the data source. The rule is that either you have the `DataSourceID` set in the declarative part of your code (`*.aspx`, `*.ascx`) and the binding is done automatically upon each postback OR you bind programmatically which involves setting the data source and calling the `DataBind()`.

My recommendation would be to move your `ObjectDataSource` to the declarative part of the code and set the `DataSourceID` on the `FormView` to the `ID` of the `ObjectDataSource`. This is clean and easy and the binding works always.

Comment: Zychia thank you for the feedback.  I discovered that I had negelected to add the datasource so I add a line to my code, see above.  With regard to adding the data source ID in the declarative part of my code, I did not do that for the page load because I am using a different source depending certain conditions, as you can see in the if (source == LifeLineDS) statement.  Is there a better way to handle a situation like that?

Comment: apologies for messing up your name in my comment above :)